# Space before first word after .join array to string

Tags: ruby

To convert array to string I used [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) and got space between the
beginning of the string, first quote mark, and the first word. I do not understand why this is happening.

I resolved with `String#strip` but I would like to understand

```
def order(words)
  arr_new = []
  arr = words.split(" ")
  nums = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
  arr.each do |word|
    nums.each do |num| 
      if word.include? num 
        arr_new[num.to_i] = word
      end 
    end
  end 

  arr_new.join(" ").strip 
end 


order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a")
```

Without .strip the output is:

```
" Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
```

After .strip:

```
"Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
```

Comment: You can use compact instead of strip like `arr_new.compact.join(" ")` so it will remove additional spaces from middle of given string also if we don't have integer in sequence.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're seeing the extra space is because arrays in ruby are 0 indexed, so you have an nil array element because your first insert is a index `1`

```
x = []
x[1] = "test"
```

This creates an array as such:

```
[
  nil,
  "test"
]
```

If you created an empty array named `x` and assigned `x[10] = "test"` you'd have 10 nil values, and the word "test" in your array.

So, your array, before joining, is actually:

```
[nil, "Thi1s", "is2", "3a", "T4est"]
```

You have a couple options:

- Change your strings to start with zero
- Change your assignment to adjust the offset (subtract one)
- Use `compact` before you join (this will remove nils)
- Use `strip` as you noted

I'd suggest `compact` because it would address a few edge cases (such as "gaps" in your numbers.

More info in the [array docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html)

Answer (score 0):

[@Jay's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56729213/2423164) is indeed correct.

I'll simply suggest a cleaner version of your code that doesn't have the same problem.

---

This assumes that the 1-9 order isn't dynamic. Aka wouldn't work if you wanted to sort by random characters for example.

```
def order(words)
  words.split.sort_by { |word| word[/\d/].to_i }.join ' '
end
```